# При нажатии кнопки в диалоге приложение падает

Tags: java, android, button, android-dialog

По нажатию на обычную `FloatingActionButton` вывожу диалоговое окно (без кода, на котором падает приложение - модальное окно работает ).
Далее должна была бы быть обработка нажатия кнопки (которая находится на модальном окне) но вот на этом месте приложение и падает. Возможно обработчик нужно переместить в другое место или указать явно с использованием this? Впрочем, что конкретно делать я не знаю. Подскажите пожалуйста!

```
private int counter = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
            dialog.show();
            //инициализировали наш массив с элементами списка
            final ArrayList<View> allView = new ArrayList<View>();
            final ScrollView container = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.container);
            Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    counter++;
                    // береи данные из edit'a
                    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    float data = Float.parseFloat(editText.getText().toString());
                    //берем наш кастомный лейаут, находим все его элементы
                    final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null);
                    ImageView deleteImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageDellete);
                    TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                    text.setText("Событие A" + counter +"=" + data);
                    //добавляем все что создаем в массив
                    allView.add(view);
                    //добавляем елементы в контейнер
                    container.addView(view);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Привожу скрин с ошибкой:
[image: android monitor]

Answer (score 4):

Вчитайтесь внимательно в логи: скорее всего 44-я строка вот эта:

```
addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

Верно?

А значит вот здесь:

```
Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Вы присваиваете `null` вашей переменной `addButton`. Видимо, вы ошиблись указывая `id`, или где-то ещё.

Answer (score 1):

В другом ответе верная причина, но нет решения. А происходит это потому, что вы ищите свою кнопку не в той разметке. Вы обращаетесь к разметке активити, а надо к разметке диалога:

```
final ScrollView container = (ScrollView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.container);
Button addButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button);
...
EditText editText = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

возможно есть и другие виджеты из разметки *dialog_layout.xml*, принцип я думаю вы поняли.